# OnGoing Notification on status bar using user preference checkbox

Tags: android, notifications, android-preferences, android-notifications, preferenceactivity

How can i display a onGoing notification using the userpreferences and the checkbox?I want disaply the battery level that is in my MainActiviy:

```
        private BroadcastReceiver batteryInfoReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {         

            int level= intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL,-1);
                     . . .

            String[] statusbatt = {
                "Battery level: " +level+"%",
                . . .};
            ListView lvStatus = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv_status);
            lvStatus.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, R.layout.list, statusbatt));
            info.getListViewSize(lvStatus);      
          }
};
```

the settings preferences:

```
public class Settings extends SettingsActivity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.settings);

    final CheckBoxPreference checkboxPref = (CheckBoxPreference) getPreferenceManager()
            .findPreference("Checkbox");
   ////// here the check box code for notfication
   }
}
```

As you can see i don't know how do it. Any help?
the checkbox in the settings.xml:

```
<CheckBoxPreference
        android:defaultValue="true"
        android:key="first"
        android:summary="@string/summary_show"
        android:title="@string/Show_notifications" />
```

Comment: I'm looking for this argument a lot online but i can't find anything! How is it possible? There are a lot of applications that ask if you want display the notification or not through a checkbox in the preferences bu none talk about how do it.

Comment: Have you looked at the [Notifications guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html)? It doesn't look like you're using the Notification API anywhere in your code snippets.

Comment: What i want is to give a possibility if want display the notification or not through the preferences screen but i can't.. i can't find any guide about it. No examples..

Comment: You'll have to manage this yourself. Show a checkbox, read its state, write that state to SharedPreferences, and later check that SharedPreferences entry when you want to decide whether or not to use the Notification Manager to show a notification.

Comment: have you got some examples?

Comment: Start by going through the Notifications guide I linked earlier and use its examples to get your app to show a notification at all, first. Then you can wire it up to the settings code you've already written.